# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel with Room Database in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel

I need to create an application to work with a database. But when creating the model I get an error: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.carexpenses.viewmodels.CarViewModel

The error is given by the line where application is used. How can this be fixed?

My ViewModelClass

```
class CarViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val carDao : CarDao
    private val allCars: LiveData<List<Car>>
    
    init{
        val db = MainDB.getDatabase(application)
        carDao = db.carDao()
        allCars = carDao.getAllCars()
    }
    
    fun getAllCars(): LiveData<List<Car>> {
        return allCars
    }
    
    fun insertCar(car: Car) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            carDao.insertCar(car)
        }
    }

}
```

My DataBase class:

```
@Database(entities = \[Car::class\], version = 1)
abstract class MainDB: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun carDao(): CarDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MainDB? = null
    
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MainDB {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MainDB::class.java,
                    "main.db"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Create ViewModel in Fragment:

`carViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[CarViewModel::class.java]`

I can't find a solution, everything works without using the database, when it is connected, everything stops working

Answer (score -2):

The problem wasn't because of the ViewModel. Everything didn't work because of the implementation: implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'

After deleting the error disappeared, hooray